# Merging two list with a mask

Tags: python, numpy

If have a boolean list two lists

The sum of two lists length is equal to the mask length
Is there an efficient way to merge this two list?

Example

```
 mask   : array([False, True, True, False, False])
 list a : array([3, 4])
 list b : array([1, 2, 5])
```

```
 if True fill in a if False fill in b 
 output : array([1, 3,  4, 2, 5])
```

Intuition way

```
 a_count = 0
 b_count = 0
 output = np.zeros(mask.shape)
 for i in range(len(mask)):
   if mask[i] == True:
     output[i] = a[a_count]
     a_count += 1
   elif mask[i] == False:
     output[i] = b[b_count]
     b_count += 1
```

But it's to slow. 
How can I improve the speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with arrays and masking:

```
mask = np.array([False, True, True, False, False])
a = np.array([3, 4])
b = np.array([1, 2, 5])

# create output array
out = np.empty_like(mask, dtype=int)

# select elements from out that are True in mask -> set them to a
out[mask] = a
# if False set to b 
out[~mask] = b

out
>>> array([1, 3, 4, 2, 5])
```

Comment: Thanks, help me a lot